# kinesis agent to lambda, how to get origin file and server

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I have a kinesis agent that streams a lot of log files information to kinesis streams and I have a Lambda function that parses the info.
On Lambda in addition to the string I need to know the source file name an machine name is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can add it to the data that you send to `Kinesis`.

`Lambda` gets `Kinesis` records as `base64` string, you can encode to this string a `JSON` of this form:

```
{
  "machine": [machine],
  "data": [original data]
}
```

And then, when processing the records on `Lambda`: (`nodejs`):

```
let record_object = JSON.parse(new Buffer(event.Records[0].kinesis.data, 'base64').toString('utf8'));

let machine = record_object.machine;
let data = record_object.data;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Kinesis Agent to produce data stream. I see that the opensource community has added ADDEC2METADATA as a preprocessing option in the agent. The [source code](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-agent/blob/master/src/com/amazon/kinesis/streaming/agent/processing/utils/ProcessingUtilsFactory.java)

Make sure that the source content file is of JSON format. If the original format is CSV then use the CSVTOJSON transformer first to convert it to JSON and then pipe it to ADDEC2METADATA transformer as shown below.

Open agent.json and add the following:

```
    "flows": [
        {
            "filePattern": "/tmp/app.log*", 
            "kinesisStream": "my-stream",
            "dataProcessingOptions": [
{
                    "optionName": "CSVTOJSON",
                    "customFieldNames": ["your", "custom", "field", "names","here", "if","origin","file","is","csv"],
                    "delimiter": ","
                },
                {
                    "optionName": "ADDEC2METADATA",
                    "logFormat": "RFC3339SYSLOG"
                }
            ]
        }
    ] 
}
```

If your code is running out of a container/ECS/EKS etc. where the originating info is not as simple as collecting info about bare-metal EC2, then use "ADDMETADATA" declarative as shown below in the agent.log file:

```
{ 
    "optionName": "ADDMETADATA",
   "timestamp": "true/false",
   "metadata": {
   "key": "value",
      "foo": {
        "bar": "baz"
      }
    }
  }
```